# How can I fix a call to undefined function libraries_load() in GeShi Filter?

Tags: 7

I just installed [GeSHi Filter](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter) and had to install the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) for it. When I try to go to configuration settings I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function libraries_load() in /home/username/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/geshifilter/geshifilter.module on line 23
```

For the moment, I uninstalled all the above modules and its back to normal. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you tried to use the recommended branch of Libraries API (marked green): 7.x-1.0. Generally, this is a good thing to do, but it can cause problems when modules have dependencies that are still in development.

In this case, Libraries API 7.x-1.0 doesn't the define the `libraries_load()` function that GeSHi Filter needs. You need to use the [latest 7.x-2.x development snapshot](http://drupal.org/node/1044008).

Answer (score 2):

As reported in [the project page](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter), you should use the development snapshot 7.x-2.x-dev of the Libraries API module for the branch 7.x-1 of the GeSHi Filter module.

> The 7.x branch requires the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) (2.x-dev). A [drush make file](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) is also included that will download both the libraries API and the geshi dependency.